# Android: Make the native media player load the video from URL

Tags: android

Dear experts I face a problem loading Video file from the URL in my Android app. 
In my app when I click the button a web page is opening. In the bottom of the page I have buttons. One of them should have such functionality. If you click on it, a view appears automatically which contains a media payer icon.(This is have done).The icon contains link to video file. By clicking on that icon the video specified in Url should play. This is the whole scene. Now I can't really implement the part where I give the button its functionality that is make the video to play.
Thanks a lot beforehand